# android asynchronous messages sometimes execute quickly and sometimes slowly

Tags: android, message

During the development of Launcher, it was found that when switching navigation mode, the asynchronous messages sent are sometimes scheduled quickly and sometimes very slowly.

I tried to replace asynchronous messages with synchronous messages to solve this problem, but I want to know why asynchronous messages sometimes schedule faster and sometimes slower.